# How do I make this 'slider' javascript to simply rotate images infinitely?

Tags: javascript, image, rotation

I'm trying to help out a friend who has a rotating pane on his homepage where the images don’t scroll on an infinite loop.  They scroll through and then roll back to the beginning and start again.

Here is the Javascript snippet he provided:

```
$(function () {
    if ($('#customScroller').length != 0) { //check if we're on the right page
        var width = $('#slider a').length;
        $('#slider').width(width * 930); //give the slider the appropriate width
        var count = 0;
        initial slide position

        function slide() {
            if (count < (width - 1)) { //we want to check if at end of the slider
                count++;
            }
            else {
                count = 0;
            }
            var toMove = 0;
            toMove = (-1 * (count * 930));
            $('#slider').animate({
                left: toMove
            }, 1000, function () {
                //complete
            });
        }
        var s = window.setInterval(slide, 8500);
    }
});
```

How much work is it to convert it to simply cycle infinitely?

EDIT:  Here is the site:  http://www.ralphshardwood.com

Comment: Put it in a loop and reset the counter when it's maxed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to appraoch this differently. To achieve your desired effect, you will want to absolutely position your slides off the right edge of your container, and animate the next one from the left, ensuring it has a higher z-index (rather than move the entire list, which is maintaining your order.

You can get the gist below and can take this into your existing markup. Here's a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/mGeqx/

```
if ($('#slides').length != 0) {
    var currentIndex = 0, slides = $('#slides > li');
    $(slides[currentIndex]).css('left','0%');
    function slide() {
        var current, next;
        current = $(slides[currentIndex]);
        currentIndex++;
        if(currentIndex === slides.length){
          currentIndex = 0;   
        }
        next = $(slides[currentIndex]);
        next.css('left','100%');
        next.css('z-index',parseInt(current.css('z-index'), 10)+1);
        next.animate({left: '0%'}, 1000);
    }
    var s = window.setInterval(slide, 2000);
}
```

Markup:

```
<ul id="slides">
    <li>Slide1</li>
    <li>Slide2</li>
    <li>Slide3</li>
    <li>Slide4</li>
    <li>Slide5</li>
</ul>​
```

CSS:

```
ul#slides {position:relative; width:400px; height:200px; overflow:hidden;}
ul#slides > li {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:100%;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#777;
    color:#FFF;
    z-index:1;
}

ul#slides > li:nth-child(even) {background:#444;}
```

​